# Peano's Existence Theorem - Constructing Maximum and Minimum Solutions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Suppose that $D=[a, b] \times \mathbb{R}$ is a strip in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and that $f(x, y)$ is continuous and bounded on $D$. Let $(x_0, y_0)$ be an interior point of $D$ (i.e. $a< x_0 <b$).

Prove that there are two integral curves $y=\phi_1 (x)$ and $y=\phi_2 (x)$, i.e. the maximum and the minimum solutions to the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x, y)$, such that

(1). $\phi_1 (x_0)=\phi_2 (x_0)=y_0$ and $\phi_1 (x)\geq \phi_2 (x), \forall x\in [a, b]$;

(2). the region $\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | a\leq x \leq b, \phi_2 (x)\leq y\leq \phi_1 (x)\}$ can be completely filled by integral curves passing through $(x_0, y_0)$;

(3). There are no solutions (integral curves) to $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x, y)$ passing through $(x_0, y_0)$ that lies outside the region in (2).

Below is a sketch of solution given by my TA.

By Peano's existence theorem, since $f$ is continuous and bounded on $D$, there exists, in a neighborhood of $x_0$, some function $y=y(x)$ such that $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x, y)$ and that $y(x_0)=y_0$.

By fundamental theorem of calculus, we have that

$$y'=f, y(x_0)=y_0 \iff y(x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^{x} f(t, y(t))dt$$

Let $y_{max}$ be the largest integral curve and $y_{min}$ the smallest. Then

$$y_{max}-y_{min}=\int_{x_0}^{x} \Big[f(t, y_{max}(t))-f(t, y_{min}(t))\Big] dt\geq 0$$

**These may be constructed using an Euler approximation on the integral to recursively build the max and the min**. Any integral curve in-between may also be created since we may take any value between the max and the min in the recursion.

The idea he presented is very natural, but what is confusing me is the bolded part. I really have no idea how to build the max and the min recursively. Can anyone explain how to proceed? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence in bold is correct and means the following:

At each step of the subdivision **always take the maximum** or **always take the minimum** of the possible derivatives on the corresponding interval. Each of the constructions will converge uniformly to solutions, indeed the maximal and minimal solutions (although one should point out that these claims are not obvious).

Comment: Thank you. I'm still a little bit confused. So suppose we take $[a, b]=[-1, 2]$ and $(x_0, y_0)=(0,0)$. Assume that $f(x, y)=\sqrt{|y|}$, then $y(x)=\frac{x^2}{4}$ if $x\geq 0$ and $0$ if $x<0$, is a solution to $y'=f$. In this case, what is $y_{max}$ and what is $y_{min}$? Sorry but I mean isn't the 'possible derivative' just $f$?

Comment: As you wrote: the idea is to use the "Euler approximation", not to solve the equation explicitly. And yes, for example $y(x)=0$ is also a solution.

Comment: Oh I think I got it. So we are dealing with the slopes of the linear approximations (tangent lines). Suppose we have our $y$. The tangent line at $x_1=x_0+\epsilon$ takes the value $y_0+\epsilon f(x_0, y_0)$. And by always maximizing (or minimizing) $\epsilon$, we obtain the optimized approximation. Is it correct?

Comment: Precisely !  :-)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the idea is to take small $\epsilon$ and take the largest value of $f$ on each $\epsilon$ interval to construct $y_{max}$ (and then take the smallest value of $f$ for $y_{min}$) as a limit of these curves as $\epsilon$ approaches $0$. Then I suppose it is obvious that $y_{max}$ is greater than $y_{min}$ and also that they intersect at $(x_0,y_0)$. Furthermore, it is pretty clear that no solution passing through that point can be outside the area. But how do you show that the area between the min and max functions is "filled in"?

Comment: @Peter A rough idea is that by selecting at each step values of $f$ that are between the smallest and largest values you can reach $\delta$-near any point of the area in between. Then you need to use a density argument by letting $\delta\to0$ (assume on the contrary that there is a gap at some time $x$, and make sure that you construct a sequence of approximations always with $\delta$ smaller than the size of the gap).